# Update Table from another table without similar values

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have just taken over the database and found that there are many areas where the data stored is not standardized. Records of operator's name are not stored in a standardized way. I am working towards standardization so that it is easier to analyze data. The following are the 3 tables that i need help with. I need to update the information on the table called TimeCards.

tblEmployees

```
ID   FirstName LastName    Num
234  Saijimon  Joseph306   306
235  Pasquale  Partipilo   299
```

The main problem with this table is that there are Numbers inside the last name as shown on ID 234, but some others are perfectly normal as shown on ID 235. I have made a new table below to rectify the changes.

tblEmployeeMain

```
 ID   FirstName LastName    Num
 234  Saijimon  Joseph      306
 235  Pasquale  Partipilo   299
```

Now to the main issue. I have a table below whcih gets its information from a form. And the form uses information from tblEmployees

tblTimeCards

```
TimeCard#    Employee         Hours
27742        Joseph306        35
27743        Partipilo        36
```

Is there a way to update all the existing entries in tblTimecards such that the information stored is shown as below?

```
TimeCard#    Employee                   Hours
27742        Joseph Saijimon 306        35
27743        Partipilo Pasquade 299     36
```

The following is the query which i try to use, but since there is no joins, i am stuck with what to do.

```
UPDATE  tblTimeCards
SET tblTimeCards.Employee = tblEmployeeMain.[Last Name]+" "+tblEmployeeMain.[First Name]+" "+tblEmployeeMain.[no]
WHERE tblTimeCards.Employee = "Joseph%" AND tblEmployeeMain.[Last Name] = "Joseph" ;
```

I am not familiar with the update query.

Comment: Can you change the design of *tblTimeCards* to include a foreign key which references the employee identifier number in *tblEmployees*?

Comment: oh... I see what you are trying to do... let me try... Thanks!

Comment: I am unable to do so due to restriction in admin rights.. is there any other round abouts i can try

Comment: Are the **LastName**s unique? Or does the **Employee** include the **Num** for all people, where **LastName** is not unique? If the latter is the case, do you still have the original **tblEmployees** with the respective records holding the combination of (the actual) **LastName** and **Num**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column called **ID_Employee** to the **TimeCard** table. This column plays the role of a foreign key which can be used to create a relationship between table **tblEmployees** and **TimeCard**.

```
CREATE TABLE TimeCard
(
    Timecard INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Employee VARCHAR(50),
    Hours INT,
    ID_Employee INT
)
```

And then use the following code to update the specific data in the table TimeCard

```
UPDATE TimeCard
SET Employee = tblEmployees.LastName + ' ' + tblEmployees.FirstName + ' ' + CAST(tblEmployees.Num AS VARCHAR)
FROM tblEmployees INNER JOIN TimeCard
ON tblEmployees.ID = TimeCard.ID_Employee
```

In the actual form of tables that you provided, you can not bind the data between table **tblEmployees** and **TimeCard**.

Comment: How do you update the new column with the ID values then?

Comment: and so i created a new column for IDs(which is num in this case) for tblTimeCards, then updated the IDs for tblTimeCards. Finally Updated using the tblEmployeeMain

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update tbltimecard with tblemployemain in that case you are supposed to use update with join

```
 UPDATE  tblTimeCards 
SET tblTimeCards.Employee = tblEmployeeMain.[Last Name]+" "+tblEmployeeMain.[First Name]+" "+tblEmployeeMain.[no] 
from (select timcard#,First name, Last name, no from tblemployeemain)
WHERE tblTimeCards.timecard# = tblEmployeeMain.timcard#;
```

Comment: That wouldn't work since there is no timecard# in tblEmployeeMain

Answer (score 0):

The following works in MS SQL Server 2008.

```
UPDATE tblTimeCards
SET employee = (SELECT CONCAT(lastName, ' ', firstName, ' ', id)
                FROM tblEmployeeMain
                WHERE tblTimeCards.employee =
                      CONCAT(tblEmployeeMain.lastName, tblEmployeeMain.num)
               )
WHERE employee LIKE '%[0-9]'
  AND CHARINDEX(' ', employee) = 0
;

UPDATE tblTimeCards
SET employee = (SELECT CONCAT(lastName, ' ', firstName, ' ', id)
                FROM tblEmployeeMain
                WHERE tblTimeCards.employee = tblEmployeeMain.lastName
               )
WHERE employee NOT LIKE '%[0-9]'
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69592/2).
Sorry, no MS Access at hand to verify.

Please comment, if and as adjustment / further detail is required.